# How to improve velocity of Java code invoking webservice and logging the whole process?

Tags: java, web-services, log4j, slf4j, wsimport

I made a Java application that reads some rows from a table on Oracle and then invoke a web-service for each row taken.
This process is taken more time than expected. About 4 rows per second are being invoked, I would expect about 50 rows per seconds.
I used wsimport tool to generate the files to access to the webservice. All the process is being logged with libraries slf4j and Log4j.
What can I do for improve the velocity of the whole process?
Could multi threading help in this case?

This is a brief of my code:

```
query = "select * from table name where to_char(DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') >= '"+tMin+"' and to_char(DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') < '"+tMax+"'";

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:"+connection_string);
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while( rs.next() ){

    SomeBean n = new SomeBean();
    n.setColumn1(rs.getString("Column1"));
    n.setColumn2(rs.getString("Column2"));
    n.setColumn3(rs.getString("Column3"));
    n.setColumn4(rs.getString("Column4"));
    n.setColumn5(rs.getString("Column5"));
    v.add(n);   

}

for(SomeBean s : v)
{   

    String Column1 = s.getColumn1);
    String Column2 = s.getColumn2();
    String Column3 = s.getColumn3();
    String Column4 = s.getColumn4();
    String Column5 = s.getColumn5();


    someInfo1.setColumn1(Integer.parseInt(Column1));
    someInfo1.setColumn2(Column2);
    someInfo1.setColumn3(Column3);

    someInfo2.setColumn4(Column4);
    someInfo2.setColumn5(Integer.parseInt(Column5));

    try 
    {                       
        Result resultws = Webservice.webservice(someInfo1, someInfo2);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //catch exception
    }
}
```

[image: VisualVM - CPU sample]

Comment: Did you try to use a profiler like JProfiler or JVisualVM to identify the bottleneck?

Comment: Yes, I used VisualVM but I don't know where to look at and what to do about it. I posted a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi threading can help you here beacause is row processing is independent. There are many approaches. I would suggest to use ExecutorService from java, that will basically creates a ThreadPool on which you submit a web service call ([ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)). But the most simple solution is to wrap your web service call in a Runnable like this

```
new Thread(
            new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Result resultws = Webservice.webservice(someInfo1, someInfo2);
                }
            }
    ).start();
```